# SSH connection in cronjob denied :"No supported authentication method"

Tags: 14.04, ssh, cron, remote

I wanted to set up `crontab` to fetch resources from remote server to local server.

Steps used as below

In local server

1. `ssh-keygen` with no passphrase
2. copied the pubic key over to the server using SCP

In the remote server

1. `cat id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
2. edited `.ssh` config file `sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config` as below:

   ```
   RSAAuthentication yes
   PubkeyAuthentication yes
   ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
   PasswordAuthentication no
   UsePam no
   ```
3. reload ssh by `sudo /etc/init.d/ssh reload`
4. Changed permissions:

   ```
   sudo chmod 700 .ssh
   sudo chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
   ```

After all this configuration, neither I am able to access remote server by public key or normal login credential into remote server.

If I tried to login through PuTTy asked for my login after has been entered. Its says:

> Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server send: publickey)

If I tried to login through SSH from local server `ssh sana@127.168.1.1` it says:

> Permission denied (publickey)

Server Details: Ubuntu 14.04, I set up public key with another user not with root user.

Comment: Your chmod command will only change the folder, not its contents, so you want to add a -r in there (or is it -R? it is the recursive flag, check the man pages). I also think you want 640 or 644 but not 100% on that. I don't see why you would want your .ssh directory to be executable under any circumstances, so at worst 600 should do. I could be wrong on that, though. My .ssh dir is all rw-rw-r-- (664) and is functional. The authorised_keys files on my servers are all rw------- (600).

Comment: Are you sure you are using your private key and not just trying to ssh with sana user? Take a look at https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/logging-in-with-an-ssh-private-key-on-windows/ in this section "PuTTY: Logging in with the Private Key" Note: In future whenever you try to change your ssh configuration, leave one ssh session open and check your ssh login in next terminal.

Comment: The folder is supposed to be 700, the .pub file should technically be 644, while your private key should be 600.

Comment: Please look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys again to verify you did everything correctly. Beyond that you can ask SSH to generate debugging messages with more details rejection reasons: `ssh -vvv ...` on the client and `sudo sshd -ddd` on the server (shut down the SSH daemon first). Please [edit] your question to include the output of the two (see [How do I save terminal output to a file?](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814)).

Comment: I can't see anything wrong in your workflow. Hope you can get it fixed. @XtrmJosh: If you have no clue, you should think about not commenting, because most of what you said is simply wrong.